# Ubuntu 18.04 + Dell XPS 9360 = Suspension doesn't work when I close the lid

Tags: suspend, xps, 18.04, lid, systemd-logind

I upgraded to 18.04 after 16.04 had no way to make the touchpad work.

The only issue with 18.04 is that when I close the lid (with or without external monitor) the laptop does not suspend.

*How can I patch this?* I read some instructions for 16.04 - 17.10 that point to edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and change the file to this:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
HandlePowerKey=suspend
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
HandlePowerKey=suspend
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

Comment: I had same issue on a Lenovo e11... still not working. Posted it on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390276&p=13760358#post13760358

Comment: And suspend works if you call it manually?

Comment: yes, if I call it manually it works

Comment: Same issue on Dell XPS 9370 after an upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04.

Comment: After installing (not upgrading to) 18.04 on an XPS 9360, I have had no issues with suspend when closing the lid.

Comment: After saving `logind.conf` you need to run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service` or reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: Can you try the fix I suggested on [18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036122/390863Ubuntu)?